# How can I have 2 colors in an Actor, like a cube with 2 colors for example? [VTK]

Tags: c++, vtk

Let's say I have a cubeSource, and at the end I have a cube actor. Is it possible to divide this cubeActor into 2 colors, so one side is a color, and the other is another one? Even if I apply transformation matrix on the actor (rotation or translation), I would like it to keep these colors at each side of the cube.

Edit : There is an example that helped me do this : http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/NamedColors

Comment: No - you have to change (split) the pipeline before it gets to the actor

Comment: Does that mean I have to create 2 cube source with their own color and find a way to combine them to make one actor?